# Wildfly 10 Deployment Error WFLYCTL0184: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10, persistence.xml

We are migrating JBoss AS 7.0.2 to Wildfly-10.0.0.Final. We have faced some of the dependencies problem while deploying the web application.

When I start deploying my app, it return me the error specified in the title with the following...

Jboss Log :-

```
12:45:27,151 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management task-10) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /apps/app/jboss/standalone/data/content/ae/706772b622ad784903380eafdc9cd93c25afd3/content 
12:45:28,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "app-8.20.war" (runtime-name: "app-xxx.war")
12:45:40,074 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,075 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry activation.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,075 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,075 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,125 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.1jboss.patch01-brew.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,126 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.1jboss.patch01-brew.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,126 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry concurrent-1.3.2.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.1jboss.patch01-brew.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,126 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry antlr-2.7.2.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.1jboss.patch01-brew.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,155 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry activation.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,168 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,168 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,168 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,168 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry activation.jar in /content/app-xxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.12.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:45:40,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPOJO0001: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).
12:45:40,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx
12:45:40,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for org.jbpm.task.xxx
12:45:41,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.task.xxx'
12:45:41,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx'
12:45:41,243 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: org.jbpm.task.xxx
...]
12:45:41,250 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx
...]
12:45:41,532 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
12:45:41,534 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
12:45:41,536 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
12:45:41,666 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
12:45:41,670 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
12:45:41,681 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
12:45:43,549 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
12:45:46,294 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management task-10) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app-8.20.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.persistenceunit.\"app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.appDS]",]}
12:45:46,309 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.task.xxx'
12:45:46,308 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx'
12:45:46,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment app-8.20.war (runtime-name: app-xxx.war) in 109ms
12:45:46,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management task-10) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.appDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.task.xxx".__FIRST_PHASE__, service jboss.persistenceunit."app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx".__FIRST_PHASE__, service jboss.persistenceunit."app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx".__FIRST_PHASE__] 
  service jboss.persistenceunit."app-xxx.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxx".__FIRST_PHASE__ (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."app-xxx.war".POST_MODULE] 

INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYDR0009: Content /tnq/apps/jboss/standalone/data/content/ae/706772b622ad784903380eafdc9cd93c25afd3 is obsolete and will be removed
INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /tnq/apps/jboss/standalone/data/content/ae/706772b622ad784903380eafdc9cd93c25afd3/content
```

Persistence file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
         xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">



         <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.xxxx" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appDS</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/ProcessInstanceInfo.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.task.xxx">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Attachment</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Content</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.BooleanExpression</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Standalone.xml :-

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/appDS" pool-name="MySqlDS1" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:mysql://172.16.73.78:3306/sampleDB
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                    com.mysql
                </driver>
                <transaction-isolation>
                    TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                </transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>
                        10
                    </min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>
                        100
                    </max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>
                        false
                    </prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>
                        false
                    </use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>
                        FailingConnectionOnly
                    </flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        test
                    </user-name>
                    <password>
                        test
                    </password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>
                        select 1
                    </check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <validate-on-match>
                        true
                    </validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>
                        false
                    </background-validation>
                    <use-fast-fail>
                        false
                    </use-fast-fail>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>
                        5000
                    </blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>
                        60000
                    </idle-timeout-minutes>
                    <set-tx-query-timeout/>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        0
                    </prepared-statement-cache-size>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>
                        com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
                    </xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

I would like to resolve that dependencies. Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you configure the datasource `appDS` in your standalone.xml file?

Comment: Thanks @Apostolos   yes, we configured datasource in standalone.xml

Comment: standalone.xml  added here for references.

Comment: This issue has been resolved after we exclude the hibernate package in WildFly Server by using jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF of project folder.